How can I alter the behaviour of a builtin renovate group?
We use renovate to update our .NET NuGet Packages, and we use
extends: ["group:monorepos"]

to pick up renovate's builtin list of known monorepo groups.
I would like to alter the configuration for some of the builtin groups - specifically, the group:dotnetMonorepo one. I'd like renovate to automatically create PR's for minor/patch versions, but ignore major versions, as we want to upgrade them manually.
If I'd defined the groups myself, I could do something like
{
    groupName: "dotnet monorepo",
    matchPackagePatterns: [... however this is defined ...],
    matchUpdateTypes: ["major"],
    enabled: false
},

But given that renovate has already defined the group, I can't find any way in their documentation to alter the existing group.
Is this possible? or do I have to opt out of group:monorepos and declare all groups manually?
